# Sockets in android to connect to database

Tags: android, database, sockets

I want to connect with external database. I have port, host, login, password. Which tool I have to use? May it be Sockets? If may not, what else I need to use? How to connect with external database programatically from android?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why would you want to do this? I can understand maybe for a database management app, but otherwise you should access the DB through some kind of web-service

Comment: Database management app is what I am trying to do. I just want to browse my tables, could edit and delete them, sorting results and stuff like that.

Comment: For a direct DB connection you would need to use the MySQL driver and I think it's unlikely to work on Android.. so it's better that you just use a web-service (preferably REST) to expose your database